# GA4- Number of page views is duplicated on the first visit for each user

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4, event-tracking

i'm facing an issue with Google analytics 4, Page_view events count is showing 2 counts when i open the page for the first time.
in another meaning when I enter a page for the first time the count is increased by 2 .. and if i entered the same page again the count is increased by one [which is the right thing].

How can i fix it, knowing that i'm not adding any custom event or props.

removing all the custom integration code .. keep the simple integration

Answer (score 0):

If you are not doing something tricky with the configuration of GA4, then the second pageview probably comes from automatic pageviews on history change events that GA4 tries to track. This is a new feature of GA4 in order to simplify tracking on Single Page Applications (SPAs) or SPA-like applications, but it rarely works as expected.

I would propose to turn of this option off. You can find it in Admin → Stream → Enhanced Measurement Settings (the icon) and under "Show Advanced settings":

[image]

Comment: if the answer worked correctly consider voting as correct so this question can be considered resolved :)

Comment: i try this solution but when debug view it's still trigger multiple page view even when i didn't reload the page. any idea? does this take time to see the effect?